# Create Resource in .java file

Tags: android, resources

Can I create and modify Resource like layout or TextView in activity (.java file) but not in Res folder ? In normal, I have to create it in Res and link to activity by their id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can dynamically create your views and inflate them using LayoutInflater in your java code.
If you already have xml file with you, you can use this http://37.46.125.53/xmltojava/ to convert it to java code.

For example:

XML layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="20dp">
</TextView>
```

Java code:

```
TextView textview = new TextView();
textview.setWidth(30); // needs to be calculated based on certain conditions
```